# How to solve the g++ problem "internal compiler error: Illegal instruction min() _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { return __FLT_MIN__; }"?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, ubuntu, gcc

On `Ubuntu`, `gcc 8.3.0`,I compile `test.cpp` file:

```cpp
#include<algorithm>
int main(){}
```

```sh
g++ -o test test.cpp
```

and get the following compile error

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/uniform_int_dist.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:66,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/algorithm:62,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/limits:1599:7: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction
       min() _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { return __FLT_MIN__; }
       ^~~
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
```

The problem is may be caused by `<algorithm>`? After trying, when I use c++98, the problem doesn't appear, for example:

```sh
g++ -o test test.cpp --std=c++98    //compiling succeed
g++ -o test test.cpp --std=c++11    //compiling fail
```

I have reinstalled gcc and the error remains.
In fact, I have a `.cpp` file that requires `c++11`, so I want to know how to compile `.cpp` files including `<algorithm>` through c++11.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, this is a GCC 8 bug. That's why the error message points you to `Readme.Bugs`. There's a [PPA](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-gcc-compiler-on-ubuntu-18-04/) for the newer GCC 9.

Comment: I install g++-9 and try again, but it makes no difference. It seems that someone has submitted the bug, but they haven't deal with it yet. Thanks.

Comment: That suggests a deeper problem. Is your CPU compatible with your Ubuntu version? "Illegal Instruction" might refer to e.g. an AVX2 instruction that's missing from processors that are a decade old.

Comment: My CPU is G5400, it is not an old CPU. In fact, I have compiled the same c++ program on the same PC successfully months ago. At that time I used g++ that is packaged with ubuntu 19.04 ISO. I don't remember its version, so now I install g++-7 g++-8 g++-9, and they all fail. Maybe this error appears because of some updates of ubuntu? Or maybe I configure something wrong. I will test it on another ubuntu PC soon and find some causes. By the way, how can I know whether GNU has fixed this bug or not?

Comment: Even I faced the same problem in GCC `9.3.0`. The problem is fixed in GCC `10.1.0`